# Get the value of a rect attribute(fill color) in Testcafe with typescript

Tags: javascript, testcafe

I've the following code:

```
<colored-item label="Label A" symbol-size-left="9.5" symbol-size-right="12" symbol-right="" symbol-left="<svg viewport="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" stroke="black" fill="rgb(0, 91, 142)" stroke-width="0" />
  </svg>" small-font="true"></colored-item>
```

and I need the value of the "fill" attribute("rgb(1, 89, 138)").

I tried the following:

```
const fillColor = await Selector('colored-item').getAttribute('symbol-left');
```

The result is:

```
<svg viewport="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" stroke="black" fill="rgb(1, 89, 138)" stroke-width="0" />
  </svg>
```

When I try

```
const fillColor = await Selector('colored-item').withAttribute('symbol-left').getAttribute('fill');
```

the result is "null"

Any ideas how to access the "fill" attribute directly?

Otherwise I need to use regex, right?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you put the SVG element in the attribute of the `colored-item`. But to display this SVG on the page, it should be added to the DOM.
Testcafe tries to search elements by DOM, so it means you should research DOM elements on the page and find out which selector you need to use exactly. According to the information that I see, you can get these attributes directly from `rect`:
`await Selector('rect').getAttribute('fill')`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. The above code is a nested html which is what appears on the displayed page. Therefore it isn't possible to access the the rect as a selector. I've tried that already... but thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it via regex:

```js
const fillColor = await (Selector('colored-item').getAttribute('symbol-left')).match(/fill="?([\d\w\(\ \,\)]*)"/)[1];
```

If you want to use it just substitute `fill="` with your string expected to exclude and at the end the

```js
" 
here 
)"/
```

with your expected end character (or string if needed)

The result will be a match and a group. Just select the group by adding `[1]` as seen above.